# SQL server 2000, return number of cells with the same values

Tags: php, html, dynamic, html-table, sql-server-2000

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
```

For example I have the following data in a table, now I want to count rows with the same values so that I will have:

```
1 = 3 (cells with the value of 1 returns a count of 3)
2 = 4 (...)
3 = 1 (...)
```

I want to get results like this because I want to create a dynamic rowspan on an html table... Any help would be appreciated.. by the way I am using php and mssql server 2000..

Comment: do you want to return all the data in 1 query, or pass in a single value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select count(*) from table where field=value;
```

Edit:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) m
 , SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'f' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) f
 FROM members;
```

This thread might help:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,397163,397178

Comment: thanks orbit, it helps alot..just a little bit of modifications then i can solve my problem soon,, many thanks :)